# NoReverseMatch within a template action url

Tags: regex, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I have this URL in my main urlconf:

```
url(r'^confirm-invite/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$', confirm_invite, name="confirm_invite_page"),
```

This is the (WIP version) view that it is hooked up to:

```
def confirm_invite(req, token):
    template_name = 'invites/confirm_invite.html'

    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = ActivationForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            try:
                auth_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=form.cleaned_data['activation_code'])
            except:
                return HttpResponse('didnt authenticate')
            if auth_user is None:
                return HttpResponse('auth_user is none')
            login(req, auth_user)
            return HttpResponse('you activated your account')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('form error foo')
    else:
        invite = get_object_or_404(Invite, token=token)
        user = invite.user
        if user.is_active == True:
            return HttpResponse('user is already active')
        else:
            form = ActivationForm()
            return render(req, template_name, {'form': form})
```

And here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'confirm_invite_page' token %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Activate">
</form>
```

For some reason the reverse URL in the HTML, `{% url 'confirm_invite_page' token %}`, is throwing out matching problems

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/nirla/apps/invites/views.py" in confirm_invite
  78.               return render(req, template_name, {'form': form})
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  532.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  452.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /confirm-invite/6f0ce05c8404470bb996f20c8271e363/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'confirm_invite_page' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['confirm-invite/(?P<token>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

I thought this was set up correctly considering the docs, what is the problem with the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the last line to

```
return render(req, template_name, {'form': form, 'token': token})
```

Because otherwise, the template does not have this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is "token" None? It seems to be based on the stacktrace. You need to make sure that variable is set to some value, or else the url template tag will fail since it will be looking up a match where there url has no arguments in it, even though yours clearly does.

Comment: What do you mean is token "None"?. Token is passed into the URL that renders the page. I suppose I can do assignment within the view, but that doesn't seem to make sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: In your template, is the context variable token not defined? It doesn't seem like you're passing it into the view. The url template tag requires that you pass all the necessary args/kwargs for your url into it. An easy test to see if this is the problem is to replace "token" with "1" or some else trivial. So you could try: {% url 'confirm_invite_page' '1' %}.